# How to strip out src="" value with twig from iframe code

Tags: templating, twigextension, plaintext

I have have a text field for copy-pasting an iFrame code.

```
<iframe src="https://webpagelink.com/l/3556456/2019-03-06/34576" width="100%" 
height="500" type="text/html" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" 
style="border: 0"></iframe>
```

What I need help with is striping out the URL within the `src=""` value from the iframe. Is this possible using Twig?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you want to _remove_ the `src` attribute from the iframe HTML code, or do you want to strip everything _but_ the `src` attribute (e.g. end up with a variable containing the URL in the original `src` attribute)?

Comment: Yeah like Mats I'm curious what you're trying to achieve here...

Comment: @MatsMikkelRummelhoff - My client copy/pastes iframe codes in, and now we realized that I need to inject a variable with entry.title into the iframe. So yes, I just need to get the url only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a module that adds a twig extension to return the value of src from the string. That way you get to utilise PHP as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17017684/how-to-get-url-from-the-iframe-using-php to get the value.

https://pluginfactory.io/ is a good starting point for adding a module to Craft.

alternative very dirty approach: If the iframe markup is always going to be the same, you could do `|replace()`, replacing everything before the `src="` and everthing after the `" width` with empty strings. Then replace `" width` with an empty string.

Comment: Thank you @mijewe! Never built a plugin, but yes, it will always be generated iframe from a Pardot form every time. I think I will try and get the |replace to work.